# Java parsing this particular string without unique delimeters

Tags: java, parsing, html-parsing

I have a string like this

```
String a = "background-image: url(www.google.com); background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-background-size: 1001px 1903px;height: 1903px; width: 1001px; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;";
```

I have to get the height: and width: values from the String and replace it with user inputted values from the form.What would be the best way to parse it?

Comment: Regular expression of "[0-9]+px", 3rd match is height, 4th match is width

Comment: @Laurence Can U explain in terms of code

Comment: Do you want the values as `int` eg `1903` or as `String` eg `1903px`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split by semicolon then by colon and create a map.

```
String a = "background-image: url(www.google.com); background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-background-size: 1001px 1903px;height: 1903px; width: 1001px; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;";
HashMap kv = new HashMap();
for(String b : a.split(";")){
    String[] temp = b.split(":");
    kv.put(temp[0], temp[1]);
}
```

Then you can just set the values by key

```
kv.put("height", "2048px");
kv.put("width", "86em");
```

The HashMap `toString` method produces output similar to the original. You will just have to tweak it a bit

```
kv.toString().replaceAll("=", ":").replace("{", "").replace("}", "")
```

one caveat to note is the order of keys gets jumbled up and is not "in order" of what the input string is

```
height:2048px, text-align:center, -webkit-background-size:1001px 1903px, width:86em, margin:0 auto, background-repeat:no-repeat, background-image:url(www.google.com)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to extract it. You need only one line for each:

```
String height = html.replaceAll(".*(?<=height: )(.*?)(?=;).*", "$1");
String width = html.replaceAll(".*(?<=width: )(.*?)(?=;).*", "$1");
```